# Underscore templating - changing token markers

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

Out of the box underscore templating uses the markers `<%= %>` for raw, and `<%- %>` for HTML escaped content.

I know you can change the markers using something like:

```
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;
```

But how does this relate to raw and escaped content? It looks to me like you end up with only one type of marker. Or have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Underscore.js documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) says this (emphasis added):

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off interpolated code. Define an interpolate regex to match expressions that should be interpolated verbatim, **an escape regex to match expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped**, and an evaluate regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without insertion into the resulting string.

So you can just give the `_.templateSettings` object an `escape` property:

```
_.templateSettings.escape = /\{\{-(.*?)\}\}/g
```

```
>>> compiled = _.template("Escaped: {{- value }}\nNot escaped: {{ value }}")
>>> compiled({value: 'Hello, <b>world!</b>'})
"Escaped: Hello, &lt;b&gt;world!&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;
Not escaped: Hello, <b>world!</b>"
```

Comment: Ah thanks - missed that bit. Would be more useful if they were to include both settings in the example code though.

Comment: Users who want their JS (for example, `if` statements) in the template to also be evaluated when using curly style brackets should also look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18411901 (use the `evaluate` setting).