# Render Backbone Template Variable In Quotes

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, pug

Hi I'm using Backbone to render a Jade template into HTML. The view looks like this:

```
script(type="text/template",id="waiting_call_template") 
    div(class="call-code") <%= channelId %>
    div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-right: 20px; width: 130px;")
      div(class="statistic", title='<%= fullPage %>') <%= page %>
```

When that renders, the HTML output looks like this:

```
<div title="&lt;%= fullPage%&gt;" class="statistic">test.html</div>
```

This is happening because the fullPage variable is in quotes. How do I get Backbone to recognize that fullPage is a variable even though it's in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you change the markers to {{- varName }} by using this script:

```
_.templateSettings.escape = /\{\{-(.*?)\}\}/g
```

In your situation you will have to change the template into:

```
script(type="text/template",id="waiting_call_template") 
    div(class="call-code") {{- channelId }}
    div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-right: 20px; width: 130px;")
      div(class="statistic", title='{{- fullPage }}') {{- page }}
```

source: [Underscore templating - changing token markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802402/underscore-templating-changing-token-markers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
div(class="statistic", title=<%= fullPage %>)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to print something between the quotes, use "#{}" syntax:

```
div(class="statistic", title="#{fullPage}") #{page}
```

Comment: that makes Node think that the variable is coming server side, when it's actually supposed to be filled in by Backbone

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the escape() function from underscore?

From the [Underscore manual](http://underscorejs.org/):

> _.escape(string)  Escapes a string for insertion into HTML,
>   replacing &, <, >, ", ', and / characters.

Comment: Not sure what this would do / how you're proposing I use it exactly. The problem is that Backbone doesn't recognize the variable when it's in quotes. Will escape help that?

Answer (score 0):

Just un-escape your template. Using underscore 'unescape'. In your backbone:

`_.template( $('#tmpl-following').html() ),`

change to

`_.template( _.unescape( $('#tmpl-following').html() ) ),`