# Knockoutjs and changing template dynamically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I use a knockoutjs with templating plugin ([Using Underscore Template with Knockout using interpolate due to asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410055/using-underscore-template-with-knockout-using-interpolate-due-to-asp-net))
If i have a header and a list:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'people' }"></ul>
<script type="text/html" id="people">
    <h2>{{= hdr}}</h2>
    {{ _.each(people(), function(item) { }}
        <li>{{=item.name }} ({{=item.age }})</li>
   {{ }); }}
</script>
```

also a button

```
<button id="bindclick">Click</button>
```

and a ja code where i use knockout:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    hdr: "People",
    people: ko.observableArray([{name:"name1",age: 45},{name:"name2",age: 33}])
});
```

How to do, that template value can be change with clicking a button instead of "Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."?:

```
$("#bindclick").click(function() {
    ko.applyBindings({
        hdr: "People2",
        people: ko.observableArray([{name:"name1",age: 45}])
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: [Dynamically Changing Templates in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-dynamically-changing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need to call applyBindings once with a model object.

Later on in your click handler, you would simply update your model.

For example:

```
var theModel = {
    hdr: ko.observable('People'),
    people: ko.observableArray([{name:"name1",age: 45},{name:"name2",age: 33}])
};

ko.applyBindings(theModel);

$('#bindclick').click(function () {
    theModel.hdr('People2');
    theModel.people([{name:"name1",age: 45}]);
});
```

Updating the model should update your previously bound content.