# Using Underscore.js template within Knockout.js doesn't allow me to use "if" binding

Tags: knockout.js

I want to use unserscore.js template to speed up some of my code. I referred the following question.

[Using Underscore Template with Knockout using interpolate due to asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410055/using-underscore-template-with-knockout-using-interpolate-due-to-asp-net)

Here is the working example from the link above,
http://jsfiddle.net/6pStz/433/

However, once I include "if" binding inside a template, it gives me an error saying "This template engine does not support the 'if' binding within its templates ".

Here is the example,
http://jsfiddle.net/6pStz/488/

```
<script type="text/html" id="peopleList">
    {{ _.each(people(), function(person) { }}
        <li>
            <b data-bind="text: person.name"></b> is {{= person.age }} years old
        </li>
   {{ }) }}
    <!-- This if binding is the issue -->
    <!-- ko if : test -->
    <div data-bind="text:testString">test</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

Please check the console if you are on Chrome, there should be the error. I guess I need to tweak for the "if" binding for the underscoreTemplateEngine, but I've no idea what I should do.

Comment: As I commented on Max Brodin's answer, I don't think that there is an easy way for two template engines working together. As I already implemented with ko templates heavily, I decided to manually modify DOM with underscore.js where it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` binding uses knockout template engine, use underscore template instead

```
{{ if (test) { }}
   <div data-bind="text:testString">test</div>
{{ } }}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pStz/489/)

Comment: I was actually thinking that two template engines can get along together somehow. I already implemented tons of templates with ko, but some parts are very slow with 'foreach', so I just wanted to replace them underscore.js. Your answer wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it is indeed the solution, thanks anyway.